Modelling multiple events with a single `eventfd`
I am not sure if this is the best stack exchange community to post this on since it is kind of in the intersection between number theory and computer science/software engineering.
Linux's eventfd API is a convenient and efficient way to notify another process of an event that occurred and how many times it occurred.
I will summarize the API like so with three function:

create - Create a new eventfd resource with an initial value for an internal counter.
read - Read the internal counter's value and reset it to zero; If it is zero, the process will be blocked until the internal counter gets a non-zero value.
add (write in terms of Linux's implementation) - Atomically add a positive value to the internal counter and wake other threads currently sleeping on a read.

Let's say we would change the API and instead of an add we would have a mult.
This way we can multiply prime numbers together to notify that different kinds of events happened.
For example, if I were to mult to the counter the value $2^3 \times 3^7$ in one thread, and in another I would multiply with $2^2 \times 5^4$. On the read side I would get the total value $2^5 \times 3^7 \times 5^4$ and then using prime factorization I can figure out that the event that is represented by prime number $2$ occurred 5 times, the event represented by $3$ occurred 7 times, and the event represented by $5$ occurred 4 times.
Is there a way I could model such thing using the API as it currently is (i.e. using only an add)?
By "such thing" I mean using only addition, is it possible differentiating between events and how many times each one occurred?
This is not a programming question. I know that I can just use multiple eventfds, one for each event (and it would probably be more efficient than whatever the solution is, if there is one, to this question).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is this a math problem or a computer problem?

I would say it is a math problem with constraints posed by a computer system. Is it really that unclear? I can try to rephrase it to the best of my ability

Purely mathematically, not taking floating point precision into consideration, I'm thinking about logarithms, since $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y).$
